# How do I activate "dense roster" on Google Hangouts?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

For some random reason, perhaps in another bid to gain user engagement, Gchat in Gmail is being suddenly replaced with Google Hangouts. It says that if I like it looking the way it is now, I'm encouraged to choose the "dense roster" setting.

Where is this setting? It doesn't seem to be anywhere in Gmail settings.

Comment: Not a random reason. Google announced the permanent retirement of GChat a few weeks ago.

Comment: Announcing it makes the decision less random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to visit https://hangouts.google.com.
"Use dense roster" is easily found within Gmail (left panel) by just clicking the little down arrow by your Icon/username in the chat/hangout area. You don't even need to navigate Settings.

Comment: Didn't notice that you could scroll down in that window, so I didn't see it when I looked there myself at first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go the actual hangouts site, hangouts.google.com, and change it in the settings there. God forbid a feature incorporated into gmail has its settings incorporated with it.